# Add static route to a route the is supposed to be dynamic?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In my routes file, `web.php` I have,

```
Route::get('/m/{game}', 'CommentController@index')->name('game');
Route::get('/m/{game?}', 'GameController@all')->name('all');
```

But can I add "static" routes, for example:

```
Route::get('/m/snes', 'GameController@snes')->name('snes')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrange your routing to make the static at top, so laravel routing will find the static first rather than go to the `/m/{game}` and `/m/{game?}`

Answer (score 2):

Put this route:

```
Route::get('/m/snes', 'GameController@snes')->name('snes');
```

Before the other routes to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the static route on top of your dynamic routes.

```
Route::get('/m/snes', 'GameController@snes')->name('snes')
Route::get('/m/{game}', 'CommentController@index')->name('game');
Route::get('/m/{game?}', 'GameController@all')->name('all');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the static route before the other routes. What happens is that when Laravel is checking which route to use when you go to m/snes, it checks the routes until it reaches a match. So if you have:

```
Route::get('/m/{game}', 'CommentController@index')->name('game');
Route::get('/m/{game?}', 'GameController@all')->name('all');
Route::get('/m/snes', 'GameController@snes')->name('snes')
```

Laravel notices that the first route is valid, since m/snes means that "snes" can be the {game} variable.

If you put the static route on top, however:

```
Route::get('/m/snes', 'GameController@snes')->name('snes')
Route::get('/m/{game}', 'CommentController@index')->name('game');
Route::get('/m/{game?}', 'GameController@all')->name('all');
```

as soon as it reaches it it notices it's a match. And if your intended URL was something like m/n64 it keeps on searching until it finds a match (in this case, it would be the next route on the list). This is a common ocurrence on routing files, even across JS projects.